# Context in Facebook's React JS framework

Tags: javascript, web-frameworks, reactjs

I'm struggling to understand how context works in Facebook's React JS framework.

When passing a specification to React.createClass, certain methods (notably event handlers) seem to require the use of React.autoBind to 'bind callbacks to the component'. Other methods (notably `render()`) don't have this requirement but still happily reference `this.props` or `this.state`.

*What is the context of 'this' as used by the `render()` method, if it's not the component ?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because they kind of already does `autoBind` for internal methods such as `render`. In fact, if you call `autoBind` and pass those methods you'll get an error.

For custom methods, initially the idea is that you might want to stick to whatever context you want to assign, but this is changed in 0.4.x (http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html).

Basically because the bound `this` is most of the time what you want, from now on every method in `createClass` will now `autoBind` by default.

Answer (score 0):

In any component framework (not just react), event handlers need manual management of the `this` reference because they're registered into the DOM as a callback *function*, not *method*. In react 0.3 you could bind the `this` reference yourself, or you can use `React.autoBind` which is more efficient. In React 0.4, all event handlers get bound by the framework on their way into the DOM, so you don't have to think about it anymore.

thus the `this` reference is always a reference to a react component instance.